# Dropping unused levels in facets with ggplot2

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2

Is it possible to drop levels that are not used in ggplot2s facets? This is my code:

```
tab = as.data.frame(cbind(groups = mtcars$cyl, names = row.names(mtcars), val = mtcars$mpg, N = mtcars$disp))
tab$N = as.numeric(tab$N)

ggplot(tab, aes(names,val)) + 
geom_point() + coord_flip() + 
theme_bw() + 
facet_grid(groups ~ ., drop=TRUE)#, scales="free", as.table=F, space="free")
```

I tried the `drop=T` switch but it doesnt help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For pure programming (not stats) questions like this, please migrate to StackOverflow

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Your example data just doesn't have any unused levels to drop. Check the behavior in this example:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = runif(12),
                  y = runif(12),
                  grp1 = factor(rep(letters[1:4],times = 3)),
                  grp2 = factor(rep(LETTERS[1:2],times = 6)))

levels(dat$grp2) <- LETTERS[1:3]

ggplot(dat,aes(x = x,y = y)) + 
    facet_grid(grp1~grp2,drop = FALSE) + 
    geom_point()

ggplot(dat,aes(x = x,y = y)) + 
    facet_grid(grp1~grp2,drop = TRUE) + 
    geom_point()
```

It may be that you're looking to change which factors are plotting on the vertical axis in each facet, in which case you want to set the `scales` argument and use `facet_wrap`:

```
ggplot(tab, aes(names,val)) + 
    geom_point() + coord_flip() + 
    theme_bw() + 
    facet_wrap(~groups,nrow = 3,scales = "free_x")
```

Comment: Oh i see now what it does. My intention was to plot only those levels in every facet, that are actually grouped by the facet. Like, using my tab example,`dotchart(as.numeric(tab$val), labels=tab$names, groups=tab$groups)`. Is it possible?

Comment: @mrrrau Yes, see my edit.

Comment: For future readers, `drop` drops any factor levels that weren't used in *any* facet of the plot, while `scales` drops any factor level that wasn't used in a particular facet of the plot.  This took me a while to understand from this post, so I thought I'd clarify here to save someone else the trouble.

Comment: @JakeFisher Thanks for pointing this out!  Quite helpful!